# How to set columns in a table to behave with respect to other columns of the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm creating a data base that contains a table called 'payments'. In this table, you can pay with three methods, one of the methods is credit card. Let me use the table below for better illustration, the table name is payment.payments

PaymntID | creditcardnumber | creditcardexpdate | Creditcardholdersname | PaymentMethodID

Now, my task to leave the creditCardnumber, creditCardExpDate and Creditcardholdersname empty if credit card is not the payment method, but otherwise, none of the columns should be left empty. still haven't got a solution. thanks

Comment: Sounds like you should have a separate table for credit card payment with the relevant columns as `NOT NULL` and just make an entry in that if they paid by card. Sure you should be storing this anyway?

Comment: This is an incorrect design.  What happens if you want to add a 4th credit card type?  A 5th? You need an architecture that can handle an arbitrary number of credit cards, which calls for a separate table linked to the primary table by a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `check` constraints.  In the `create table` statement, these would look like:

```
check (method <> 'cc' and cc_col1 is null and cc_col2 is null and cc_col3 is null and cc_col4 is null),
check (method = 'cc' and cc_col1 is not null and cc_col2 is not null and cc_col3 is not null and cc_col4 is not null)
```

You can also add them using `alter table`.

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of a broken design.  I know you're answering the letter of the question, but you should take this opportunity to explain why this approach is wrong.

Comment: @JimGarrison . . . I disagree.  This is a common format for putting data into tables.  Although some might like ultra-normalized structures, some do not.  I would encourage you to learn about dimension tables, starting with Ralph Kimball's books on the topic.